# Exponential Shift Operator with another differential Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have the following Problem:
$$\exp(-t\nabla_x\nabla_y) \exp(\frac{1}{2} y^\intercal C(x) y)\vert_{x,y=0}$$
where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $C(x)$ is a covariance Matrix, i.e. its positive definite. Now naively I would shift the $y$ coordinate by the differential Operator $\nabla_x$ and end up with (after setting $y=0$):

$$\exp(\frac{t^2}{2} Tr((\nabla_x \otimes \nabla_x ) C(x)))\vert_{x=0} $$ where the differential Operators act on the components of the covariance matrix.
Is this the correct way?

Comment: could you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question, deleting...

Comment: Maybe consider the  pde $F(x,y,t)_{,t} =- \nabla_x \nabla_y F(x,y,t)$?

Comment: I understand that it my expression if the solution of this PDE, but I need to solve the integral. Since the Covariance matrix depends on x, I cannot just simply shift y by a differential operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you Fourier transform by $y$, you will get $$e^{{1\over 2} y^TCy}\sim \det(C)^{-d\over2}\int e^{iqy}e^{{1\over2}q^{T}C^{-1}q}dq$$ and so $$e^{-t\nabla_x \nabla_y} e^{{1\over2} y^TCy}\sim\int dq e^{iqy}  e^{itq\nabla_x}  \det(C)^{-d\over2}e^{{1\over2}q^{T}C^{-1}q}dq$$
Now we can shift the $x$:
$$\int dq e^{iqy} \det(C(x+itq))^{-d\over2}e^{{1\over2}q^{T}C(x+itq)^{-1}q}dq$$
and setting $|_{x,y=0}$:
$$\int dq \det(C(itq))^{-d\over2}e^{{1\over2}q^{T}C(itq)^{-1}q}dq$$
For whatever this is worth.

Comment: This is an expression I got earlier but, as you can see, its an Integral of a gaussian with Covariance Matrix depending on the integration variable. I dont know what to do with it. Do you perhaps have any ideas?

Comment: No. I think it is hopeless unless you know some of the structure of $C$.

Comment: I do know the structure of C, but its not simple. x would be a 3n vector, consisting of n 3 dimensional vectors. C can be described as a nxn block matrix with 3x3 blocks C_ij. The entries of C_ij would then depend on the absolute value of the difference between ith and jth vector x_i, x_j. So quite ugly.... thats why I was looking to solve it with differential operators...

Comment: Maybe just expand in $y$ and $x$ since you are looking for the limit. Since $y$ is quadratic, this selects only the even powers of $(\nabla_x \nabla_y)^n$ in the operator.